# How to deploy a Finder Sync extension project

Tags: deployment, macos-high-sierra, findersync

I have created a simple Hello World application using Xcode on Mac High Sierra. To this i have added a Finder Sync extension. In the requestBadgeIdentifierForURL API, i am doing a HTTP webrequest to my Sync app in order to get the status of the file and accordingly set the overlay badge icon (synced ok, conflict, error etc). 
I am running it in debug mode and it works fine.. can see the overlay icons when i open the Sync folder in Finder.

I am completely new to Xcode and Mac.
Now, I need a way to deploy this in a live environment. What is the process for the same? Please help!

Comment: You should check https://developer.apple.com/macos/distribution/.

Comment: Its not good idea to keep webrequest in finder sync extension.